# Creating Heatmap graph in R?

Tags: r, graphics, heatmap

This is my rfm_table dataframe:

```
 UserID    R F      M Rsegment Fsegment Msegment Total_Score
1  10609  984 3 318.78        2        4        4         244
2  10922  648 1 184.26        5        2        3         523
3  11300 1022 1  91.02        2        2        2         222
4  11400  864 5 851.73        3        5        5         355
5  11487  797 1 147.22        3        2        3         323
6  11762 1042 1  32.31        1        2        1         121
```

I want to craete a heatmap using with R(Recency),F(Frequency) and M(Monetary) columns just like this image at below[image]

I used "plotly" package and wrote this codes following but getting this error

```
# minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels
plot_ly(z = rfm_table[,c(5,6,4)]
        x = c("1","2","3","4","5"), y =c("1","2","3","4","5"),
       type = "heatmap")
```

Can anyone explain What Should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used package ***plotly*** or any of its functions. Here are alternative solutions, including the one that works form me the best (from package lattice).

Raw data (by the way, it would be VERY helpful if you have provided test data like this rather than just a printout like you have above...)

```
d1 <- data.frame(UserID = factor(rep(paste("id", 1:10), 50, sep = "")),
                 RR = factor(rep(1:5, 100)),
                 FF = factor(rep(1:5, each = 100)),
                 MM = round(1000*rnorm(500), 2))
table(d1$R, d1$F)

# Means of groups, long format
d.l <- aggregate(x = d1$M,
                 by = list(RR = d1$RR,
                           FF = d1$FF),
                 FUN = mean)

# Same data, wide format
d.w <- reshape(data = d.l,
               idvar = "RR",
               timevar = "FF",
               direction = "wide")
mm <- as.matrix(d.w[, -1])
colnames(mm) <- 1:5
```

Plot heatmap with color keys
Option 1: using default ***heatmap*** function

```
heatmap(mm,
        Rowv = NA,
        Colv = NA,
        xlab = "FF",
        ylab = "RR",
        main = "XXX")
```

[image]

You can add keys using legend but it takes some work.

Option 2 (my favorite): using ***lattice*** package

```
require(lattice)
levelplot(mm,
          xlab = "FF",
          ylab = "RR",
          main = "XXX",
          col.regions = heat.colors)
```

[image]

Option 3: using package ***gplots***

```
require(gplots)
heatmap.2(mm,
          Rowv = F,
          Colv = F,
          density.info = "none",
          trace = "none",
          xlab = "FF",
          ylab = "RR",
          main = "XXX")
```

[image]

Option 4: using ***ggplots***
I'm not going to write that code but you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621070/heatmap-2-with-color-key-on-top).

Answer (score 2):

Your `z` in the `plot_ly` call should be a matrix with each row-column pair corresponding to the `x` and `y` values.

```
require(plotly)
rfm_table <- read.table(text="
  UserID    R F      M Rsegment Fsegment Msegment Total_Score
  10609  984 3 318.78        2        4        4         244
  10922  648 1 184.26        5        2        3         523
  11300 1022 1  91.02        2        2        2         222
  11400  864 5 851.73        3        5        5         355
  11487  797 1 147.22        3        2        3         323
  11762 1042 1  32.31        1        2        1         121",
  header = TRUE)
df <- expand.grid(lapply(rfm_table[, 5:6], function(x) sort(unique(x))))
df <- merge(df, rfm_table[, 4:6], by = c("Rsegment", "Fsegment"), all.x = TRUE)
df <- df[order(df$Rsegment, df$Fsegment), ]
z <- matrix(df$M, nrow = length(unique(df$Rsegment)))
plot_ly(z = z, x = sort(unique(df[[1]])), y = sort(unique(df[[2]])),
        type = "heatmap")
```